# What is it and from where it is loaded?

Tags: plugins, themes, core

I am new at wordpress. I found a hook in theme back-combat.php file which is prevents to load previous version of wordpress for current theme customization. such as

```
add_action('load-customize.php', 'my_function_name');
```

My question is what is this hook and from where it is loaded because `load-customize.php`

and which way I can learn quick about wordpress core and learning plugin development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from a dynamic hook that's generated in the [`wp-admin/admin.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/71fb840a24b6b9cffe9d6a16a283b875d7247d02/wp-admin/admin.php#L318-L330) file and fires right after the `admin_init` action.

Here's the inline documentation for the core screens part:

```
/**
 * Fires before a particular screen is loaded.
 *
 * The load-* hook fires in a number of contexts. This hook is for core screens.
 *
 * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$pagenow`, is a global variable
 * referring to the filename of the current page, such as 'admin.php',
 * 'post-new.php' etc. A complete hook for the latter would be
 * 'load-post-new.php'.
 *
 * @since 2.1.0
 */
 do_action( "load-{$pagenow}" );
```

When we visit `/wp-admin/customize.php` the generated action is `load-customize.php`.

We can then e.g. check if it has already been fired with:

```
did_action( 'load-customize.php' );
```

that returns the number of times it has fired so far, during the page load.

Check the [code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/did_action/) for more info on `did_action()`.

Another example is the `wp-admin/edit.php` and the corresponding `load-edit.php` action.

Comment: you're welcome, glad to hear it helped. @Roni